# AVD crashes on windows 8.1

Tags: android, eclipse

Hello I set up an Android Virtual Device in my Eclipse ADT on windows 8.1 using the device manager.
But when I try to start it crashs.
Device is Intel/Atom(x86) Target API Level 10, Skin QVGA

The messages in logcat are. I'm wondering why the animation file is missing apparently.
04-06 23:19:13.120: E/SensorService(858): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)

04-06 23:19:14.091: W/zipro(868): Unable to open zip '/system/media/bootanimation.zip': No such file or directory

My question is there any known issues with running the emulator on windows 8.1.
Or is this a problem of my configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Intel/Atom(x86). Instead use ARM.

Comment: Thanks I tried with arm and although it didn't work every time it did work at least once. Is the Intel/Atom not appropriate for the PC architecture then. I thought you could use any provided you had the system image for it. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have faced issues with the Intel/Atom(x86), too. I don't know exactly what is the reason behind this but I guess (just guessing wild, I maybe completely wrong) that as nowadays we use x64 architecture processors in our real computers and maybe that is why the x86-based 'Intel/Atom(x86)' faces compatibility issues on x64-processor environments. You could give this a try on x32-bit environments(like on a machine running Pentium processor) and then something would be clear. Regards!